# Keep low power mode on all the time

Tags: iphone, power, ios

I would like Low Power Mode to be the default state of my device.

When I get to 80% battery it toggles itself off automatically.

How can I stop it turning itself off?

How can I always keep my phone in low power mode (or some other equivalent)?

Answer (score 10):

With ios13, you can make an automation that turns on low power mode when your phone turns it off.

[image: View screenshot]

Comment: This looks quite nice. Can't test it yet.

Comment: This is done with the Shortcuts app, go to automation tab at the bottom of the app, then click the + sign in the top left, then add a Personal Automation, select Settings | Low Power Mode, then set to OFF, and action is Low Power Mode On, and disable Ask Me before Running. https://tinyurl.com/y5lv8ebm

Comment: How to do this on ipad?

Comment: Better explained here: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/keep-low-power-mode-enabled-indefinitely-your-iphone-0207407/

Answer (score 2):

You can configure most of your phone's settings to be the same as their Low Power Mode equivalents. This includes turning off email fetch, background app refresh, automatic downloads, and iCloud photo sync. As well as setting screen lock to 30 seconds and keeping the brightness low.

[List of Low Power Mode settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205234)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this functionality as it will always turn off at 80% as the purpose of it is to extend your phone when at low battery.

From [this Apple Support discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7268548)

> Low Power Mode reduces or turns off Email fetch, Hey Siri, Background
>   app refresh, Automatic downloads, Wi-Fi associations, and some visual
>   effects. If you can live without having those features available on
>   the phone, you can keep it on low power mode. But after you charge
>   your iPhone to 80% or higher, Low Power Mode automatically turns off,
>   so you'll have to turn it back on again.

Comment: This is not helpful

Comment: @theonlygusti I said there is no way to keep it on

Answer (score 0):

Cronios lets you do so with help from shortcuts. It is not officially possible to run shortcuts in background for long.

I would like some community help in making the shortcut which runs in the background or is triggered by battery percentage hitting 80 and then toggling Low power mode on.

This workflow is not as understandable to me as compared to other languages I generally code in.

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/df0f2c800dc748d2903ccc54e2b99c24

https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/aau4iq/cronios_run_your_shortcuts_on_an_automatic/

https://routinehub.co/shortcut/1370

Also I am **not** affiliated to this product in any development or business.